# receive multiple json by $http angular

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I echo two thing like

PHP

```
echo json_encode($obj);
echo json_encode($obj2);
```

and how I receive it? I thought everything will be fall into the data param. But I got an error saying

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at Object.parse (native)

```
$http({
method: 'GET', 
url: 'path'
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

}
```

Comment: Why don't you merge the two together, encode/output that, then break them up again on with the AJAX success function?

Answer (score 1):

Seams like the second json is giving the problem. Just send one:

PHP

```
$mixed["obj1"] = $obj1;
$mixed["obj2"] = $obj2;

echo json_encode($mixed);
```